# Why didn't the .rb execute?

Tags: terminal

I'm quite new to coding and terminal. Does anybody know what the problem is below with my last command line? I'm still working on all other files from 01 to 04, and they execute normally but not the 05. I couldn't put any other new command lines after that either.
Thank you for checking on it for me. Any help is appreciated! :)

```
hienthu@Hiens-MacBook-Air Webdev % cd algorithmic_strategies_exercise
hienthu@Hiens-MacBook-Air algorithmic_strategies_exercise % ls
01_swapper.rb                           04_peak_finder.rb
02_is_sorted.rb                         05_compress_str.rb
03_bubble_sort.rb                       algorithmic_strategies_exercise.zip
hienthu@Hiens-MacBook-Air algorithmic_strategies_exercise % ruby 05_compress_str.rb
```

Comment: Is it executable? Is it executing but it makes no output? More info please.

Comment: @matt It doesn't need to be executable, just readable – but if it's locking, does it expect input? It all depends on the contents of that script.